# Create/spit out an API based from Ember App

Tags: api, ember.js, ember-cli

We currently have an Ember app that's able to process GitHub repositories. Is it possible to create an API using Ember based from the current Ember app?

Answer (score 0):

No. Ember is client side framework only, you can't create API using it

Comment: Thanks. Can we possibly hack it? Or do you have any idea about how to probably achieve such thing in some other way?

Comment: I am sure ember is not in that scope. sorry, I am not familiar with the stuff you would like to know. Maybe others will give correct suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam

Comment: look for this thing called [`koaton`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koaton)